# Change name of IText 7 field

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I'm trying to change the Text of a PdfTextFormField in an existing PDF document.

I can find the right Field and modify it's value and background color but changing it's name does nothing at all. 
I've tried removing the complete field from the dictionary, but while the size of the PDF shrinks by that the field is still in the final document.

```
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(dialog.FileName), new PdfWriter(DestinationPath2));

        PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
        IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();

        fields["Objektbezeichnung"].SetFieldName("Objectname").SetValue("Cube").SetBackgroundColor(DeviceRgb.GREEN);

        pdfDoc.Close();
```

Comment: *"tried removing the complete field from the dictionary"* - probably you removed the abstract field from the form but not the field widget from the page? Anyways, please share the pdf in question.

Comment: i sadly can not provide the pdf but how do i remove the field widget from the page? From your answer im guessing just removing it from the dictionary is not enough.